# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2014}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following series problem was in our last term test paper.

> Prove that the following series is convergent\divergent.
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2014}}$$

Please give me a help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 9):

Notice that $\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2014}}}=\left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2014}}$ and $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2014}}=0$.

Therefore $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{2014}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2014}}}=0<1$. What does the root test say ?

Answer (score 1):

For any $1>\epsilon>0$ and all $n$ sufficiently large ($n>2014$ at least), $(2014/n)^{1/2014}\leq \epsilon<1$.  Apply the geometric series test and comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>2014$, just compare with the series
$$
\sum \bigg(\frac{2014}n\bigg)^{2015/2014},
$$
which converges by the integral test.